# findVievById returning nullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I wanted to dynamicly add buttons to my linear layout, but when I try to do it line
`buttonContainer.addView(button);` returns  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

```
LinearLayout buttonContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 50);
p.weight = 1;

Button button = new Button(MainActivity.this);

button.setLayoutParams(p);

buttonContainer.addView(button);
```

Here is my XML code.

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:background="@color/darker_sky_blue"
           android:id="@+id/grid_of_buttons"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait">


           <ScrollView
               android:id="@+id/scrollView"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
               android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
               android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
               android:background="@drawable/background">
 

                <LinearLayout                 
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/darker_sky_blue">



                  </LinearLayout>

             </ScrollView>

      </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `findViewById` will only work after the view has been inflated. Is this code being run inside `onActivityCreated`?

Comment: No, how can I do it?

Comment: @Igorson  where you are writting This line of code,. Also check on your side in activity or fragment  the XML file in setcontentview using in which you are written this linearlayout

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to run your code. I placed fragments of your code inside my example activity called MainActivity and it worked without any NPE.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout buttonContainer = findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 50);
        p.weight = 1;
        Button button = new Button(MainActivity.this);
        button.setLayoutParams(p);
        buttonContainer.addView(button);
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:id="@+id/grid_of_buttons"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_purple">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have just changed the colors to android ones besides it really depends where are you calling the findViewById method. Standard way is to all call it in onCreate method in activity.